# Why my SQL can't select data from hive table through start and end dt partition?

Tags: hive

My Hive table's patition is divided by dt, which is divided by date. When I execute this SQL, it can select data from table:

```
select col_1,col_2 from table_1 where
  dt >= '2019-04-08'
```

But When I execute this SQL it can not get one result:

```
select col_1,col_2 from table_1 where
  dt >= '2019-04-08' and dt <= '2019-05-07'
```

I execute this SQL on date 2019-05-08, which means that the two SQLs's result should be the same. But the first SQL has result but the second not.
Why?

Comment: `select distinct dt from table_1 order by dt` will show for sure.

Comment: @leftjoin thank you, I execute the SQL as you showed. the table has a very big year partition, so the result is what my question shows.